# iOS Read all elements in a tabeviewcell when voice over is turned on

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I have a custom tableview cell with an image in the front and few labels in the middle and an image at the end. When voiceover is turned on and focused on the entire tableview row, all the labels are read and then when I swipe to move to the next control the first image is focused and then swiping the control moves to the second image. How to make the entire elements in the row to be read together when the entire row is focused?

Answer (score 2):

Use `shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren` and make sure that all the elements in cell are accessible. `element.isAccessibilityElement = YES;`

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615143-shouldgroupaccessibilitychildren?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

> How to make the entire elements in the row to be read together when the entire row is focused?

A `TableviewCell` must be seen as a container and, as such, the elements it contains can't be analyzed by VoiceOver if it's defined `accessible`: **you can't have the parent view and its children accessible all together** ⟹ see the example sheet of [this explanation](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#hide-elements).

If you don't want the elements inside each cell to be read out, just define each one of them as follows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
                        cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", 
                                             for: indexPath)

    cell.isAccessibilityElement = true
    cell.accessibilityLabel = "APPEND YOUR LABELS HERE"

    // Add everything you need to construct your cell here.

    return cell
}
```

With this rationale, **iOS won't read out all elements in a `TableviewCell` when VoiceOver is turned on**.